# JPanel re-sized by a Thread gets its default size when minimizing or re-sizing JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm having some troubles with what I want to do.
Basically, I have a JPanel which is re-sized by a Thread when I click a JButton. This works fine but, when I re-size or minimize and maximize my JFrame again, the JPanel gets back its default size.

Here's my Thread's class code

```
public class Slider extends Thread {

private JPanel panel;
private boolean running = true;
private int maxWidth = 0;

public Slider(JPanel panel, int maxWidth) {
    this.panel = (JPanel)panel;
    this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
}

public JPanel getPanel() {
    return panel;
}

public void setPanel(JPanel panel) {
    this.panel = panel;
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public void extendJPanelHorizontally(){
   this.panel.setSize(this.panel.getWidth()+1, this.panel.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running){
        if (this.panel.getWidth() >= this.maxWidth){
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Finishing...");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Re-sizing...");
            this.extendJPanelHorizontally();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3);
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

And my button just does as it:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Slider slider = new Slider((JPanel)this.jPanel1, 200);
    slider.start();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  2) Leave the sizing of panels to a layout manager! 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Take a look at something like [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

Answer (score 4):

Problems here:

- Your code ignores all Swing threading rules by making changes to Swing state in a background thread. Avoid this or risk having your code throw intermittent and very hard to debug exceptions.
- Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), not a background thread to solve the above problem.
- If you do use threads in the future, you're almost always better off implementing Runnable rather than extending Thread.
- Most layout managers don't respect a component's size but rather its preferredSize. You're finding this out when you change your JFrame. You can change a component's preferredSize by either calling `setPreferredSize(...)` or by overriding its `getPreferredSize()` method.